# Fuzzy c- means categorical data

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, fuzzy

Can the [fuzzy c-means](https://sites.google.com/site/dataclusteringalgorithms/fuzzy-c-means-clustering-algorithm) applied on non numerical data sets ? i.e categorical or mixed numerical and categorical..
if yes (I hope so :( ):

- how we calculate cluster centers ?

If NO , what is the alternative .. how to fuzzy clusters these data ?

I need the response please help

NOTE: I've used the Jacard's coefficient to calculate the distance between 2 points but still didn't get the way to calculate the cluster centers see the attachements[image] [image: jacard coefficient]

Comment: why is it non useful or non clear ? please tell me

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to transform your data into a numeric form. There are various ways of doing that, two of them being:

- use vectors of feature counts (common in, e.g., text categorization)
- use a one-hot representation, where a categorical feature that can take on *n* distinct values is represented as string of *n* bits, with only the *i*'th bit set if a feature has the *i*'th value in its allowed range.

Both are very common transformations that many machine learning programs do under the hood. Also, you might want to experiment with a different metric than the Euclidean one. Esp. with one-hot representation, but depending on the data, the L1 norm (Manhattan/city block distance) may be more appropriate.

Apart from that, just apply the given formulas to your transformed dataset.

Comment: thank u for ure answer, may u please check the updated question

Comment: @AWRAM: I don't think the Jaccard coefficient gives rise to a mean in the general case, so you'll want to switch to either a numeric representation or the [*k*-medoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) algorithm

Comment: suppose that we transform features to binary representation e.g I have 3 points in a cluster A having each a membership value to this cluster as follow p1(1000,0.5(membership)) p2(0100,0.7) p3(0001,0.4). How to calculate the mean in this case ?

Comment: @AWRAM: features 1, 2 and 4 occur once in your set of three while feature 3 doesn't occur, so the unweighted mean is [1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3]. The weighted case follows from this in the usual fashion.

Comment: what could be the cluster center vj mentioned above ?

Comment: @AWRAM: it's explained by the formula, isn't it? If you don't understand how to read such a formula, you might better pose a new question at math.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification:) . I know how to read it but when the xi is a binary string is it meaningful to multiply it by the membership value which is a float between 0 and 1 and would it give a valid cluster center?

Comment: Yes, it will give you the mean of the cluster. Try doing some dot products of binary vectors with real vectors, on paper, in MATLAB, NumPy, whatever -- you'll see that they make sense.